# Weighted Minimum Edit Distance

Tags: nlp, dynamic-programming

I am trying to learn about minimum edit distance. It is all good, except (check this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6f6Va.png)) I don't know how to find del[x(i)] and ins[y(j)] value. I know how to find the sub[x(i),y(j)] from this [confusion matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjyeZ.png), but I really don't know how to get the delete and insert values, even after reading some slide and watching some videos.

Comment: Maybe the text surrounding the depicted formulae tells you?

Comment: I don't think so, you can see it here
https://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/med.pdf

Comment: You need training data. The weights are task-dependent: They will be different for spelling errors from manually typed text (close keys, bad orthographical skills) compared to OCR errors (characters with close shapes), for instance. And then come different languages...

Comment: What if I use the confusion matrix as the training data? I mean it's already there, but it only explain how to use it for subtitutions, but not delete nor insert

Comment: Exactly: there should be one additional row and column each for the empty symbol. Try searching for "spelling correction training set" or whatever suits your need.

Comment: The other confusion matrices can be found in this paper http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/C90-2036. Look at section 3 and appendix.